# How to change the color of a cube with Three.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

I would like to change the color of a cube based on a radio button selection. How can I achieve this with a smooth transition?

**Radio button**

```
<input id="black" type="radio" data-color="black" name="color" value="" checked="checked">
<input id="white" type="radio" data-color="white" name="color" value="">
<input id="blue" type="radio" data-color="chamois" name="color" value="">
```

**Material**

```
var color = {

    "black": new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0x222222
    }),
    "white": new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0xffffff
    }),
    "chamois": new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0xEDE6D4
    })

}
```

**Geometry**

```
var geometry= new THREE.BoxGeometry(2,2,2);
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, color [ "black" ]);
scene.add(mesh );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Luckily for you, I implemented a solution to this a while ago - as long as you don't mind using a tweening library (I use GSAP), this code works great.

Here's the colour tweening code only (for brevity):

```
function colorTo (target, value){
    var target = scene.getObjectByName(target);
    var initial = new THREE.Color(target.material.color.getHex());
    var value = new THREE.Color(value.color.getHex());

    TweenLite.to(initial, 1, {     //This syntax is relevant to GSAP's TweenLite, I'll provide a link to the docs
        r: value.r,
        g: value.g,
        b: value.b,
        ease: Cubic.easeInOut,
        onUpdate: function() { target.material.color = initial; }
    });
}
```

[Link to full code in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/omgtoblerone/yfqwmj3q/)

**Remember**, the reason why that fiddle works is because I'm linking to two external libraries:

1. [three.min.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r71/three.min.js)
2. [TweenMax.min.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.0/TweenMax.min.js)

If you have any questions, drop me a comment and I'll be sure to answer them!

[Link to the GSAP TweenLite docs](https://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenLite/)

---

## EDIT

I've updated the answer to include functionality to trigger the tween with the radio buttons. It's important that when you create the mesh, you instantiate a `new THREE.Material()` *instead* of referencing a material already in the *color* array. Like so:

```
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x222222}));
```

Then linking it to the radio controls is no problem at all:

```
$("#inputs input").change(function(event){
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
        var targetColor = $(this).data("color");
        colorTo("box", color[targetColor]);
    }
});
```

---

## EDIT 2

In the previous example I used a super lightweight tweening plugin (`< 340 B`) which unfortunately (unbeknownst to me) was pending retirement. I have since updated the example to use a slightly more generic, and thus heavier, library called GSAP - it is nonetheless an *unbelievably* capable and lightning fast library so I wouldn't hesitate to use it.

For the last time (hopefully), happy coding!

Comment: Cool. Thanks for sharing! Do you know how to connect this with the radio buttons? So if the second radio button is checked the box is white.

Comment: @AlexanderHein Working on a solution - currently it tweens between two of the colours, but not back to black. [Here's my progress](http://jsfiddle.net/omgtoblerone/yfqwmj3q/3/)

Comment: @AlexanderHein See my **EDIT**, all finished!

Comment: You are amazing Jonathan Brooks! Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a solution for updating a whole material? http://jsfiddle.net/dz9zbk7d/

Comment: I don't, sorry! It should be noted that you need to include a light in your scene when you're using phong materials :)

Answer (score 3):

I found the color of material can be tweened directly!

```
var targetColor = new THREE.Color(0xafe2f3);
TweenMax.to( object.material.color, 2, {
                r: targetColor.r,
                g: targetColor.g,
                b: targetColor.b
});
```